# How to create a web proxy?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, proxy

I want to create web proxy . I googled it and even found some tutorial but those were in PHP.
If somebody is having tutorial of web proxy creation in java then please post it here Or simply let me know what approach should i follow to create  web proxy. [ i will be using Tomcat { if that matters for your answer } ]

Thanks

**Edit**
i guess i was not clear in stating what i require. Actually i am trying to develop a site like 'http://proxyug.com/' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSocks is a SOCKS proxy server written in Java.

http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Java Proxy servlet](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/12/simple-java-proxy-servlet-using.html). It's web proxy such as php or glype, but written in java as a servlet

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the method you'd use to create a proxy server. Not sure exactly why you refer to doing it 'in java' but based on the information below you'll just need to configure the appropriate settings for mod_proxy and would probably be better off asking this question on ServerFault:

**From The Apache Tomcat 5.5 Servlet/JSP Container
Proxy Support HOW-TO**

> Apache 1.3 supports an optional module
>   (mod_proxy) that configures the web
>   server to act as a proxy server. This
>   can be used to forward requests for a
>   particular web application to a Tomcat
>   5 instance, without having to
>   configure a web connector such as
>   mod_jk.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/proxy-howto.html